# Odoo 10 custom email send module

Tags: python, email, odoo-10, qweb

I created a module which will send email to user and here is my template.xml but i could not make python method. I looked Sale modules email method but it is not working for me. I am stack now. Which way should i follow? Can you help me please?

```
<record id="email_template_exp_prod_tag_cycle_report" model="mail.template">
                <field name="name">Life Cycle Report</field>
                <field name="email_from">>${(object.user_id.email and '%s &lt;%s&gt;' %
                    (object.user_id.name, object.user_id.email) or '')|safe}</field>
                <field name="subject">Life Cycle Report</field>
                <field name="email_recipients" />
                <field name="model_id" ref="product.model_product_product" />
                <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
                <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
    <div style="font-family: 'Lucica Grande', Ubuntu, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-color: #FFF; ">
        <p>Hello,</p>
        <p>Kindly find Report in attachment.</p>

        <div style="width: 347px; margin: 0px; padding: 5px 14px; line-height: 16px; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
            <span style="color: #222; margin-bottom: 5px; display: block; ">
            % if object.company_id.street:
                ${object.company_id.street}<br/>
            % endif
            % if object.company_id.street2:
                ${object.company_id.street2}<br/>
            % endif
            % if object.company_id.city or object.company_id.zip:
                ${object.company_id.zip} ${object.company_id.city}<br/>
            % endif
            % if object.company_id.country_id:
                ${object.company_id.state_id and ('%s, ' % object.company_id.state_id.name) or ''} ${object.company_id.country_id.name or ''}<br/>
            % endif
            </span>
            % if object.company_id.phone:
                <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; ">
                    Phone:&nbsp; ${object.company_id.phone}
                </div>
            % endif
            % if object.company_id.website:
                <div>
                    Web :&nbsp;<a href="${object.company_id.website}">${object.company_id.website}</a>
                </div>
            %endif
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
                ]]></field>
            </record>
```

And here is my not working code,

```
def generate_send_mail(self,product_ids):
        for p in product_ids:
            print p["id"].name

        ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']
        template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('product_modules', 'email_template_exp_prod_tag_cycle_report')[1]
        subject = 'Product Expiry Life Cycle Report'
        report_name = 'expired.life.cycle.report'
        if template_id and product_ids:
            ir_actions_report = self.pool.get('ir.actions.report.xml')
            matching_reports = ir_actions_report.search([('report_name', '=', report_name)])
            if matching_reports:
                report = ir_actions_report.browse(matching_reports[0])
                report_service = 'report.' + report.report_name
                service = netsvc.LocalService(report_service)
                (result, format) = service.create(product_ids, {'model': 'product.product'})
                result = base64.b64encode(result)
                file_name = subject + ".pdf"
        return True
```

I was trying so many things on my code thats why it is so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

To send a mail using template try below code

```
@api.multi
def _alert_product_expiry(self):
    for data in self:
            template_id = self.env.ref('module_name.email_template_exp_prod_tag_cycle_report')
            send = template_id.send_mail(data.id, force_send=True)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It does not give any error but also does not send email. Should I change my template.xml? Maybe email_from part is wrong. Can you explain how it should be?